# What files in node.js do I need?

Tags: filesystems, node.js, files

I am planning to download node.js onto my server. I already have all the node_modules I need elsewhere. Does this mean I can delete the folder called node_modules in nodejs?

Comment: Generally you need whatever `npm install` installs. What did your developer say about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
After you deleted node_module from your project, and run  `npm install`, all of the dependency will be downloaded into your project